# How to give div inside flexbox column item 100% height?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, height

I want to give a div inside a flex box item 100% height, but I can't get it to work. The situation is as follows:

```
#outer (display: fled, flex-direction: column, height: 100px)
  #header (height: auto)
  #middle (flex-grow: 1)
    #inner (height: 100%)
```

I want `#inner` to span the full remaining height of `#outer`. Basically, I want the red part to cover all of the green part in the fiddle below.

```css
#outer {
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#header {
  height: auto;
}

#middle {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: green;
}

#inner {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="header">
    Header
  </div>
  <div id="middle">
    <div id="inner">
      This should be full height.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Different browsers seem to deal with this differently:

- Firefox and IE displays it the way I want it, with all of `#middle` red, no green visible.
- Chrome renders it like if `#inner` had `height: auto`.

How can I fix this so it works on Chrome as well? Preferably I don't want to abandon the flexbox.

Comment: For me it works as you descibed, no green visible (Firefox, Linux)

Comment: @IiroP Interesting! I'm on Chrome 67.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `flex-shrink: 1` to `#middle` too, or just use shorthand `flex: 1` to make it work on Chrome also.

```css
#outer {
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#header {
  height: auto;
}

#middle {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: green;
}

#inner {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="header">
    Header
  </div>
  <div id="middle">
    <div id="inner">
      This should be full height.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider nesting Flexboxes such that your `#middle` is also a `flex-direction: column` flex container and `#inner` is set to grow with  `flex: 1`.

```
#outer {
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#header {
  height: auto;
}

#middle {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#inner {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
  flex: 1;
}
```

this works for me:
https://jsfiddle.net/yw6kpa1x/

Comment: IiroP's answer is better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you're looking for?

```css
#outer {
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#header {
  height: auto;
}

#middle {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: green;
}

#inner {
 
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="header">
    Header
  </div>
  <div id="middle">
    <div id="inner">
      This should be full height.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```